# Fetch currentUser data forbidden despite ACL setted on parse object

Tags: parse-platform

I'm having trouble to execute a fetch on the current user:

```
Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(user){
    success();
}, function(_error){
    error(_error);
})
```

Despite I'm adding ACL on the current object like this:

```
var newACL = new Parse.
newACL.setReadAccess(user.id, true);

user.setACL(newACL);
user.save();
```

The error message is with a 403 code with a description:

> This user is not allowed to perform the get operation on _User

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Class Level Permissions (CLPs) are set to forbid "get" operations. To solve set your class level permission to allow get in the data browser of parse. It should be the top right button that says "Security"